# Include in Project slowness with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, include, project

Our company won a web project from a new client.  Their old vendor basically zipped up the code (C#/ASP.NET, including an enormous number of media files) and FTPed it to us and is no longer answering phone calls/supporting it in any way.  There's no solution file, no project files, just code.

So I created an empty project locally and moved it to a network path and moved their code inside it because I don't even have enough space to host it locally.  Their architecture is suspect, but I need to get it back up and running ASAP so I don't have time to reconsider that at the moment.  I opened the project I created, selected "show all files" and attempted to include all of the paths (both media files and code paths) and the application hung.  One of the media folders has something like 65,000 files in it.  Do I even need to include this?

Regardless, it seems like doing "Include in Project" is taking forever, I've spent hours wrestling with it, trying to do one folder at a time...but often it's just hanging and I have to kill the process.  Is there a faster way to deal with this?  I tried editing the project file directly but including this media folder made the solution take absolutely forever to load.

Any general suggestions on how to approach this situation?

Answer (score 0):

as long there is no direct reference you don't need to include media files into the project.
I bet those files are just loaded runtime from a procedure. To make sure make a full search for the media folder in the sources.

Imho get just the files to a local store, create a solution, and then add all resources and sources. If needed you can copy the media files later again into the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I agree on the media element.  I've decided to not include that at all for the time being.  It's still taking forever to include paths that have ~100 files in them (all code).  I'm not sure what's causing it to bog down so much.

Comment: I had a similar problem with files on a network, and fixed it, but as I don't know your net, I would recommend that you move the files locally for this procedure and try out again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with local files. I probably killed VS2010 three times since it would always seem to lock up. I then recreated the folder structure, but not with the correct name, then save the project, open it with a text editor and change the names to the actual structure. Finally use "Add > Existing Item". It's still slow, but a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hanging - if you leave it long enough it will finish. Know what you mean though - it took half a day to include dojo on one of my projects.

You may want to try [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) to include large folders into your projects - it seems much, much faster than visual studio when given this task. You can then just re-open the project in vs. Hope this helps.